# Schema Locks Starting As Soon As User is Disconnected

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, schema-locks

I am having continual issues with scheme locks on our ArcSDE database, as soon as users are disconnected schema locks start appearing.  We have 20 or so feature classes and it will show anywhere from 30-90 locks at a time.  The timestamps show that they start up as soon as the user is disconnected, either by a system restart or the DBA disconnecting the user.  I am the only user; however, am not the DBA.

We are running ArcGIS for Server 10.4.1 on SQL Server R2 2012 and I am connecting using ArcGIS Desktop Advanced.  The feature classes in our enterprise geodatabase are published to our Portal as feature services and we do not use the data store.

What could be causing all these schema locks to occur, and is this something on the publisher and software user side, or on the database side?

Comment: Which user are the locks from?  Which computer are the locks from?  (You should be able to see these in the list of locks and connections.)

Comment: They are probably from my .sde connection credentials used to login to sql server, which are different than my windows authentication which is used to login to our portal. There is the possibility that something server side is connecting as my .sde user name is just “(company initials)gis” and in the list of schema locks it’s capitalized “(COMPANY INITIALS)GIS”. I don’t know if case is important though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Portal was creating connections from feature layers, I was told by esri this was by design.  SysAdmin had to kill all the scheme locks and then before they connected we versioned the geodatabase.